# Spring @RequestBody with GeoJsonPoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When trying to map POST request of GeoJsonPoint JSON to GeoJsonPoint model with no success.

The REST Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/location")
public class LocationController {

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public MyLocation recieveAddress(@RequestBody MyLocation location) {
        return location;
    }

    @GetMapping(consumes = "application/json")
    public MyLocation returnAddress() {
        MyLocation loc = new MyLocation();
        loc.setLocation(new GeoJsonPoint(0.123321, 0.3453455));
        return loc;
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class MyLocation {

    private GeoJsonPoint location;

    public MyLocation() {   
    }

    public void setLocation(GeoJsonPoint location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public GeoJsonPoint getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

}
```

The GET request return:

```
{
    "location": {
        "x": 0.123321,
        "y": 0.3453455,
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            0.123321,
            0.3453455
        ]
    }
}
```

When posting the above with debugging I'm getting:

```
DEBUG 11860 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Looking up handler method for path /location 
DEBUG 11860 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/location]
```

Searching for a solution I've to stumble with this, with no luck:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder b = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        b.modulesToInstall(new GeoJsonModule());
        return b;
    }
}
```

The Spring boot application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Can someone assist or give any direction?

Comment: The `debug` logs show that `Spring` was unable to map your request to an endpoint and most probably because the `JSON` body that is in your request does not match to the `MyLocation` object. Can you update the question with the content of `My Location` class? As well as a sample of request that you are making.

Comment: I meant `GeoJsonPoint` class not `My Location` you already have that.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated the entire scenario and both GET and POST work for me when making calls from postman. Can you check if you receive the following line during server startup?

2018-09-03 15:10:41.995  INFO 17536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/location],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json]}" onto public com.example.demo.location.MyLocation com.example.demo.location.LocationController.recieveAddress(com.example.demo.location.MyLocation)

If you get this line, means you method is ready to be accessed. Try making a call with Postman with the following configuration: https://pasteboard.co/HCba9qa.png

Make sure the posted data looks like this:

```
{
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            0.123321,
            0.3453455
        ]
    }
}
```

as there is no need to send X and Y coordinates. I have saved this data in MongoDB using MongoRepository and it works like a charm. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that correctly maps the endpoint. I suspect your issue is either of the following

1. Your incoming request body does not match the `My Location` object and `GeoJsonPoint` object hence, Spring fail to match it to the endpoint
2. You might have issues related to `Cross Origin`
3. The JSON serializer/deserializer that you are using is not working as expected
4. Your controller is not setup properly

The following works in a `Spring Boot` project with version `1.5.3` with Spring Boot's default `JSON` serializer/deserializer.

Sample `MyLocation` class

```
package com.sample.controller;
public class MyLocation {
    private CustomGeoJsonPoint location;

    //eclipse generated getters and setters 
}
```

Sample `CustomGeoJsonPoint` class

```
package com.sample.controller;
import java.util.List;
public class CustomGeoJsonPoint {
    private Double x; 
    private Double y; 
    private String type; 
    private List<Double> coordiantes;

    //eclipse generated getters and setters
}
```

Sample `Controller`

```
package com.sample.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class LocationController {
    @PostMapping("/location")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody MyLocation inDTO) {
        System.out.println("Mapped successfully!");
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the POST request made by `Postman` using `Body` -> `raw` -> `JSON (application/json)`

```
{
    "x": 12.33456, 
    "y": 33.33331, 
    "type": "Point", 
    "coordinates": [15.1234, 19.3322, 77.1234] 
}
```

Unlike you I didn't need to add a `JsonConfig`.

Comment: I think it is not the solution I'm looking for, I've already done that temporarily but the GeoJsonPoint needs to be used in MongoDB so I need to end up with the GeoJsonPoint and not custom type

Comment: I named that variable `CustomGeoJsonPoint` because it does not adhere to the structure of standard `GeoJsonPoint` and is based on JSON structure you shared in your question. You have an extra `x,y` field in there  that's why I named it `Custom`. See here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/geo/GeoJsonPoint.html

Comment: @Jonathan you ever figure this out?